# Group a sequence of rows by their first value in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

How can I group a dataset of sequences by the first value of each sequence in SQL?

For example, I have the following dataset

```
id  name  key  metric
1   alice a    0   <- key = 'a', start of a sequence
2   alice b    1
3   alice b    1
-----------------
4   alice a    1   <- key = 'a', start of a sequence
5   alice b    0
6   alice b    0
7   alice b    0
-----------------
8   bob   a    1   <- key = 'a', start of a sequence
9   bob   b    1
-----------------
10  bob   a    0   <- key = 'a', start of a sequence
```

Rows with `key = 'a'` start a new group. I want to, for example, sum the metrics for all the subsequent rows till I reach another `key = 'a'` or another `name`.

The dataset is sorted by `id`.

The final result should be this:

```
id  name   metric
1   alice  2
4   alice  1
8   bob    2
10  bob    0
```

Here's the equivalent operation in JavaScript, but I want to be able to get the same result by a SQL query.

```js
data.reduce((acc, a) => {
    if(a.key === 'a'){
      // key = 'a' starts a new group
      return [{id: a.id, name: a.name, metric: a.metric}].concat(acc)
    } else {
      // because the data is sorted, 
      // all the subsequent rows with key = 'b' belong to the latest group
      const [head, ...tail] = acc
      const head_updated = {...head, metric: head.metric + a.metric}
      return [head_updated, ...tail]
    }
  }, [])
  .reverse()
```

Sample SQL dataset:

```sql
with dataset as (
  select 
    1       as id
  , 'alice' as name
  , 'a'     as key
  , 0       as metric
  union select
    2       as id
  , 'alice' as name
  , 'b'     as key
  , 1       as metric
  union select
    3       as id
  , 'alice' as name
  , 'b'     as key
  , 1       as metric
  union select 
    4       as id
  , 'alice' as name
  , 'a'     as key
  , 1       as metric
  union select
    5       as id
  , 'alice' as name
  , 'b'     as key
  , 0       as metric
  union select
    6       as id
  , 'alice' as name
  , 'b'     as key
  , 0       as metric
  union select
    7       as id
  , 'alice' as name
  , 'b'     as key
  , 0       as metric
  union select
    8       as id
  , 'bob'   as name
  , 'a'     as key
  , 1       as metric
  union select
    9       as id
  , 'bob'   as name
  , 'b'     as key
  , 1       as metric
  union select
    10      as id
  , 'bob'   as name
  , 'a'     as key
  , 0       as metric
)

select * from dataset
order by name, id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the window function `sum()` to create the groups and then aggregate:

```
select min(id) id, name, sum(metric) metric
from (
  select *, sum((key = 'a')::int) over (partition by name order by id) grp 
  from dataset
) t
group by name, grp
order by id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a46cc9eef3c29eac5b4d5e098de42f39).
Results:

```
> id | name  | metric
> -: | :---- | -----:
>  1 | alice |      2
>  4 | alice |      1
>  8 | bob   |      2
> 10 | bob   |      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what OP wrote in the comments, the query must indeed be like this:

```sql
SELECT MAX(t.head_id) AS id,
       t.head_name AS name,
       SUM(t.metric) AS metric
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN key = 'a' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) AS group_id,
           CASE WHEN key = 'a' THEN id END AS head_id,
           name AS head_name,
           metric
    FROM dataset
) t
GROUP BY t.head_name, t.group_id
```

However, if you can add an index by name and id, it really improves the performance of the query. This because it doesn't require a sort operation before aggregating.

Testing with a table with a million rows, this is the output of explain analyse without index:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=177154.34..177158.34 rows=400 width=25) (actual time=3374.878..3489.755 rows=400000 loops=1)
  Group Key: dataset.name, sum(CASE WHEN (dataset.key = 'a'::text) THEN 1 ELSE NULL::integer END) OVER (?)
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=132154.34..157154.34 rows=1000000 width=25) (actual time=1920.338..3000.218 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=132154.34..134654.34 rows=1000000 width=15) (actual time=1920.323..2232.936 rows=1000000 loops=1)
              Sort Key: dataset.name, dataset.id
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 28192kB
              ->  Seq Scan on dataset  (cost=0.00..15406.00 rows=1000000 width=15) (actual time=0.020..172.746 rows=1000000 loops=1)

Planning Time: 0.870 ms
Execution Time: 3516.726 ms
```

By creating the index, the query plan changes to the following:

*Index*:

```sql
CREATE INDEX dataset__name_id__idx ON dataset(name, id);
```

*Query Plan*:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=90169.90..90173.90 rows=400 width=25) (actual time=1464.759..1567.778 rows=400000 loops=1)
  Group Key: dataset.name, sum(CASE WHEN (dataset.key = 'a'::text) THEN 1 ELSE NULL::integer END) OVER (?)
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.42..70169.90 rows=1000000 width=25) (actual time=0.033..1077.362 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using dataset__name_id__idx on dataset  (cost=0.42..47669.90 rows=1000000 width=15) (actual time=0.022..225.445 rows=1000000 loops=1)

Planning Time: 0.131 ms
Execution Time: 1590.040 ms
```

## Old answer

Based on your javascript code, you don't want to partition the window by `name`, nor group by `name` in the outer query. Without that, you actually end with a better query that allows you to use only the primary index, assuming that the `id` column is indexed.

```sql
SELECT t.head_id AS id,
       MAX(t.head_name) AS name,
       SUM(t.metric) AS metric
FROM (
        SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'a' THEN id END) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS head_id,
               CASE WHEN key = 'a' THEN name END AS head_name,
               metric
        FROM dataset
    ) t
GROUP BY t.head_id
```

Here is the query plan for a `dataset` with 1 million rows:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=68889.43..68891.43 rows=200 width=44) (actual time=1277.469..1393.709 rows=400000 loops=1)
  Group Key: max(CASE WHEN (dataset.key = 'a'::text) THEN dataset.id ELSE NULL::integer END) OVER (?)
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.42..51389.43 rows=1000000 width=44) (actual time=0.025..927.595 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using dataset_pkey on dataset  (cost=0.42..31389.42 rows=1000000 width=15) (actual time=0.017..209.657 rows=1000000 loops=1)

Planning Time: 0.127 ms
Execution Time: 1411.975 ms
```

Comment: In the JS snippet, I assumed that the data is already sorted by name. I put a comment about this assumption. If the data wasn't sorted, then I had to use a Map. I get your point, it makes sense if I had unique and sorted ids. That's not the case in my real dataset, unfortunately.

Comment: @homam edited the answer with that information you commented